# Is this not an incomplete answer? (low quality review)

Tags: discussion, review

[image]

I would expect it to also mention how to check folder permissions and, if required, to modify them. Perhaps I should not have recommended deletion, but modify it or add a comment. Yet, the system tells me I should have selected "Looks good", when in my view it does not.

In any case, regardless of this being a top rep user, is this answer incomplete?

The answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828405/why-cant-i-delete-or-move-these-files-without-sudo/828410#828410).

Comment: It was originally a comment and the OP asked for it to be added as an answer so he could accept it.  I don't think any further detail is necessary.

Comment: The context here is that OP knows very well how to check and change permissions. But I can see how it's a tricky audit. Don't worry about it though, that just happens sometimes - I failed one when I tried to comment the other day, and when I made the comment for real, the post author thanked me and edited, so tough luck!

Comment: Happens from time to time, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

In the context, I feel that answer has everything needed. It's clear *from the question* that the OP knows how to check and change permissions, and that information is available elsewhere on the site (the [chmod](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/chmod) and [permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/permissions) tag wikis even have some fairly helpful info I think)

Of course, *you don't have that context in review* unless you click the link, and I can see why you felt the answer needed expanding.

I usually click the link for context if I'm in any doubt (and then of course you find out it's an audit and pass ;) ) Even so, I failed an audit myself the other day because I tried to comment on a post (the context would not have stopped me - after failing the audit, I went ahead and left the same comment). I'm definitely not especially enlightened so I can't say me failing means *it could happen to anyone*, but I'm pretty sure it does happen to everyone occasionally, and although it feels bad, it is just bad luck sometimes as the system is not perfect, and you don't need to worry about the occasional one.

Thanks for all your careful reviewing :)

Comment: "I'm pretty sure it does happen to everyone occasionally" Yep, me too. I fail about one a month or so :( I have never got banned though, so the odd fail is no big deal.

Comment: heh thanks for sharing @MarkKirby :)